# Indicator synapse in tint2

Tags: system-tray, openbox, synapse, tint2

I'm using Openbox with Tint2 in Ubuntu 13.04
Is there a way to make indicator synapse ([indicator-synapse](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/spotlight-like-tool-coming-to-pear-os-other-distros)) to appear in the systray area? I  don't know why it appears in Unity but here it doesn't, because most of the apps appear normally in tint2 systay

Comment: The same thing happens for me on Openbox/XFCE. The indicator doesn't appear to be compatible with "classic systrays". No idea why that would be though or how to troubleshoot it.